# CSS Position images in specific locations inside a background

Tags: css

I have a background (used `style="background-image:url('')`) and 2 images.

I need the images to be positioned this way:

**First image:**

- 30px from top of the background
- 15px from the right

**Second image**

- 15px from the bottom of the background
- 15px from the left

my CSS classse:

1. myItem1 - first image class
2. myItem2 - second image class
3. BgGrass - the background

**What i've been trying:**

```
.BgGrass {
    background-image:url('images/bg/grass.png');
    width:800px;
    height:480px;
}

.myItem1 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left:15px;
}

.myItem2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    right:20px;
}
```

What's wrong?

Update: The solution here provided that I need to add the position:absolute to my background. The problem now is that all the content below this background is moving up inside it and making a total mess.

```
<div class='BgGrass'>

<img class='myItem1' src='http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/icons-watermarks/simple-black/raphael/raphael_gear-small/raphael_gear-small_simple-black_128x128.png' />

<img class='myItem2' src='http://iconizer.net/files/Brightmix/orig/monotone_close_exit_delete_small.png' />

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

All content here is inside the background
```

Comment: on .BgGrass put position:relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been easier if we could see the original page you're working on (html specifically)

Anyway, assuming this is your html:

```
<div class='BgGrass'>

<img class='myItem1' src='http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/icons-watermarks/simple-black/raphael/raphael_gear-small/raphael_gear-small_simple-black_128x128.png' />

<img class='myItem2' src='http://iconizer.net/files/Brightmix/orig/monotone_close_exit_delete_small.png' />

</div>
```

Then the CSS should be:

```
.BgGrass {
    background-image:url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/744081-background-wallpaper.jpg');
    width:800px;
    height:480px;
    position:relative;     
}

.myItem1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right:15px;
    width: 100px;
}

.myItem2 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:15px;
    left:15px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

CSSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ndbzg6h/

Issue: you need to add position relative to your parent div.

Comment: This works but with a problem, All the content I have placed BELOW the `BgGrass` div is moving up inside it and there is a total mess..

Comment: as I said, you'll have to show the html you're working on :) or the complete page

Comment: @TheUnreal what are you trying to reach because the answer that Nabeel Khan gave u does the thing. All content is placed inside the background .

Comment: Fixed it with adding a new div above the bg with `height:480px;`. Now all the content below the background is in below it.

Comment: maybe you're adding float to any of the divs. I'm glad that you fixed it :) if this answer helped please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score -1):

From definition [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)
`position:absolute`     The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

By default, BgGrass is static, so you must give him an other position like `relative`.

```css
.BgGrass {
    background-color:red;
    position:relative
    width:800px;
    height:480px;
}

.myItem1 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left:15px;
}

.myItem2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="BgGrass">
  
  <div class="myItem1">ABC</div>
  
  <div class="myItem2">DEF</div> 
  
</div>
```

Comment: All the elements below this background are now inside it too |: Although I used clear between them